# Django how to change where uploaded file is saved

Tags: python, django

After uploading a CSV file into a Django form and submitting, Django creates a copy of this in the project app folder. I want to be able to tell Django to store this copy in another directory. How do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked out the Django documentation for file upload? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/file-uploads/ Looks like there is a pretty simple example on there that shows how to get the file from a form and then save it in the `handle_uploaded_file(f)` method. Just swap out the example path for the path you'd want to use.

Comment: Hi Michael, in that example, the 'handle_uploaded_file' method converts whatever the uploaded file is to a txt. Is there a way to make that keep whatever format the file is when saving it in another directory?

Comment: Looks like the answer posted is probably a better way to do it than simple file handling like I mentioned but you would always write a little method to get the file extension or the uploaded file name and from there you can use that. So something like `uploaded_file.split('.')` and then grab everything after the period to get the file type. Then just use that string on the file name itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like that :

```
models.FileField( upload_to="YourFolder")
```

In your setting your can specify the folder media :

[Media URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-url)

> MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

[Documentation for the FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/files/)

If you want to specify the folder at save time :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

def upload(request):
    folder='my_folder/' 
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        fs = FileSystemStorage(location=folder) #defaults to   MEDIA_ROOT  
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        file_url = fs.url(filename)
        return render(request, 'upload.html', {
            'file_url': file_url
        })
    else:
         return render(request, 'upload.html')
```

Comment: Hi GR, that would work, but I'm trying to save the file into a folder who's name is dependent on the session number the user is currently in. I don't know how to pass that to models from views to implement into this method. The files uploaded are csv, will that still work for media url?

Comment: I have update the answer, you want to override the file storage, it is possible.

Comment: Thanks! My uploaded file is in a form, so wouldn't I need to pass the file and post into the form?

Comment: Add your view to your question